# Conditional rounding with IF statement

Tags: r, rounding

I'm trying to round numeric values in a data frame to closest interval. I want to round at different intervals based on how big the number is. I've started with this (coming from excel mindset) but I'm stuck to translate it to R code.
Note round_any rounds a number to the closest interval(e.g. 5.13->5, 5.85->6)

```
library(plyr)    
DataFrame <- sapply(DataFrame, function(x) {
       if(x>1) round_any(x,0.25),
       if(x>5) round_any(x,0.5),
       if(x>10) round_any(x,1),
       else x})
```

Could you please help me out?

Comment: What is `round_any`? Please add any packages you are using. Also note that `ifelse` is vectorized so no loop needed. In addition the correct way to update a data frame wity `*apply` would be `df[] <- lapply(df, ...)`

Comment: Thx Sotos. I've edited my post.

Comment: Take a look at the case_when and mutate in the dplyr package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `sapply` on a data frame, you are iterating over the *column vectors* rather than individual values. As such, you should be looking at vectorized conditional logic functions: just using the standard `if` control flow isn't terribly useful, as it can only take scalar (length 1) conditions.

In this case, `plyr::round_any` can take a vector as the `accuracy` argument; the `dplyr` function `case_when` could be useful here. From `?case_when`:

> This function allows you to vectorise multiple if and else if
>   statements. It is an R equivalent of the SQL CASE WHEN statement.

Here's an example for the case of a single vector to be rounded:

```r
set.seed(11)

# Generate some raw numbers
x <- runif(8, max = 20)
print(x, digits = 4)
#> [1]  5.54500  0.01037 10.21217  0.28096  1.29380 19.09698  1.72992  5.79950

# Round to differing accuracy
plyr::round_any(
  x,
  dplyr::case_when(
    x > 10 ~ 1.0,
    x > 5 ~ 0.50,
    x > 1 ~ 0.25,
    TRUE ~ 0.001
  )
)
#> [1]  5.500  0.010 10.000  0.281  1.250 19.000  1.750  6.000
```

Created on 2018-05-11 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. Based on your responses the following code worked for my data frame

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
DataFrame[] <- lapply(DataFrame, function(x){
  round_any(x,  
            case_when(
              x > 10 ~ 1.0,
              x > 5 ~ 0.50,
              x > 1 ~ 0.25,
              TRUE ~ 0.001))})
```